# Is there an open source email client that will work with Exchange 2007?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, exchange-2007, open-source

Recently I've been playing around with Ubuntu 9.04 on one of my work systems.  The only real bump in the road that keeps it from being being used as my main workstation is that I cannot find a suitable solution for an email client that works with our Exchange 2007 servers.  Ideally, I would like to implement a solution that meets the following criteria:

- The client is open source (and free)
- The solution does not require the installation of software on the Exchange server
- The solution does not require enabling POP or IMAP on the Exchange server

From what I've seen so far, it sounds like I may be out of luck (at least for the time being) though I just wanted to present the question to the community and see if anyone had any ideas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Evolution, by way of [evolution-mapi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/evolution-mapi):

```
Package: evolution-mapi
Description: Evolution extension for MS Exchange 2007 servers
 A provider for Evolution that can connect to Exchange 2007 servers
 and also to Exchange 2003, 2000 and 5.5.
```

It is very beta though, so please [report bugs](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=evolution-mapi)!

Answer (score 1):

[Evolution Exchange Connector](http://en.opensuse.org/Evolution_Exchange_Connector). Rats, not open source. My bad. Will try to find an open source one and post back. Actually, it is open source after all. Configuration to connect to Exchange [is available](http://library.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/exchange-configure.html.en).

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to run outlook under wine?

Comment: I tried installing Outlook 2003 with Wine. It installed, but it doesn't really allow you to do much more beyond that. According to the WineHQ it doesn't play nice with Wine, either.

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2526

Answer (score 1):

I run Outlook in vmware. It works pretty well.