# Scripting notifications for Outlook appointments on Linux

Tags: linux, exchange, scripting, calendar

I've a similar question to the question [Linux clients for Exchange calendar](https://serverfault.com/questions/13116/linux-clients-for-exchange-email-and-calendar). Is there any way to allow Linux workstations to fetch the appointments out of the Exchange calendar?

Unfortunately it's not possible to install additional software simply, cause new software needs to be allowed by a department of the company.

So I prefer to script things and use a tool like `notify-send` to display the notifications to the user. Using `OWA` doesn't help, because most of the people work without sound so they don't get the notifications.

Other clients like Thunderbird or Evolution are currently not allowed. So I would be really pleased if somebody could help me solving this problem.

Comment: What is this "not allowed"? You are not allowed to use them - even in user-space?

Comment: Yes rule of the company ...

Answer (score 1):

Exchange Web Services is the only way I know of that a linux workstation might be capable of doing something like this. EWS can be consumed using SOAP (and REST in Exchange 2013).

Providing a complete example would be difficult as I'm primarily Windows-based, but I thought I could help by suggesting EWS. Perhaps these links might help you on your way when it comes to examples and referencing the operations available in EWS. I hope you find what you're looking for:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_ewsrest
- http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=956618
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284867/consuming-net-web-service-using-perl-and-soap-lite

Comment: Are these web-services always available, or do they require an additional license?

Comment: @Nils. Yes they are, and it appears licensing is not an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627573/ews-exchange-web-services-license